# Why is socket not working when multithreaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I have a very simple `recvfrom()` command that works fine - so long as it is not called in "another" thread.

I would post more code, but there is quite a bit of it, so hopefully I can filter out the relevant bits: 
First we have the global variable: `SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);`.

So long as threads are not involved, this works fine:

```
char message[_max_message_];
struct sockaddr_in* from;
int r;
    int SenderAddrSize = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
    r=recvfrom(Socket,message,_max_message_,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&SenderAddrSize);
    printf("Bytes recieved: %i\nError Code: %i\n",r,WSAGetLastError);
```

Now I have identical code called behind a thread, like this:
`pthread_create(&listener, NULL, listenloop, &Socket);`

(The code basically ignores `&socket`.)

The first `recvfrom()` to execute, from the called thread, returns -1, but the `recvfrom()` from the "original" thread (where the networking was setup) successfully fills `message` with the, well, message from the server.

So kind as to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I hate to throw more than a dozen lines at strangers kind enough to help me, but I don't think I'm gonna get an answer if I don't.  So, here is the kit and kaboodle, edited slightly:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
#include <string>
//One thread shall listen continually for responses from the server.
/*The other thread shall listen continually for user input, and fire off user input at the local
 client to the server...*/

//#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
inline int randport()
{
  return (50000 % rand() + 1000);
}
#define _serverip_ "***.***.***.***"
#define _welcome_ "Welcome,Wagon!"

#define _randomport_ 64000%rand()+100
#define _max_message_ 100

void *listenloop(void *arg)
{
  //SOCKET* listener = (SOCKET)arg;
  WSADATA WsaDat;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaDat);

  char message[_max_message_];
  //SOCKET listener=(SOCKET)arg;
  int r;
  //sockaddr_in SenderAddr;
  struct sockaddr_in from;
  //while (1){

  int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
  r = recvfrom(Socket, message, _max_message_, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from,
      &SenderAddrSize);
  printf("Thread Bytes recieved: %i\nThread Error Code: %i\n", r,
      WSAGetLastError);
  return NULL ;

  //}
  return NULL ;
}

int main()
{
  string user, pass, login;
  WSADATA WsaDat;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaDat);
  int port;
  cout << "Welcome!"
  SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

  fflush(stdin); //As long as we compile with GCC Behavoir should be consistant

  //TRY NOT TO SEND PLAINTEXT PASSWORDS LIKE THIS!  IT MAY MAKE YOUR USERS VULNERABLE!  DONE FOR SAKE OF SIMPLICITY HERE!

  cout << "\n\nPlease enter the username you registered with:";
  getline(cin, user);
  cout << "\nPlease enter your password, my good sir: ";
  getline(cin, pass);
  struct hostent *host;
  host = gethostbyaddr(_serverip_, strlen(_serverip_), AF_INET);

  if (host == NULL )
  {
    cout << "\n\n UNABLE TO CONNECT TO SERVER.  QUITTING. ";
    return -1;
  }

  short errorcount = 3;
  int socketfeedback;

  ///Put the address for the server on the "evelope"

  SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
  SockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(_serverip_);

  ///Sign the letter...

  int myport = _randomport_;
  int code;

  SOCKADDR_IN service;
  service.sin_family = AF_INET;
  service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("localhost");
  service.sin_port = htons(myport);

  //bind(Socket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof(service));

  //Start a thread, listening for that server

  while ((errorcount))
  {
    code = bind(Socket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof(service));
    if (code)
      break;
    else
      return -5;
    errorcount--;
    myport = _randomport_;
    service.sin_port = htons(myport);
  }

  login = user + ',' + pass;

  if (!errorcount)
  {
    cout << "\n\nMiserable failure.  Last Known Error Code: " << code;
    return -1;
  }

  ///Begin the listen loop!!

  pthread_t listener;
  pthread_create(&listener, NULL, listenloop, &Socket);
  struct sockaddr result;
  sendto(Socket, login.c_str(), strlen(login.c_str()), 0,
      (struct sockaddr *) &SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr));

  char message[_max_message_];
  //SOCKET listener=(SOCKET)arg;

  //sockaddr_in SenderAddr;
  struct sockaddr_in from;
  int r;
  int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
  r = recvfrom(Socket, message, _max_message_, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from,
      &SenderAddrSize);
  printf("Bytes recieved: %i\nError Code: %i\n", r, WSAGetLastError);

  //SOCKET listener=(SOCKET)arg;

  WSACleanup();

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: What was the `errno` associated with the return value of -1? Call `perror` when this happens.

Comment: According to WSAgetlast error... it is a very huge number, but it is the same number for both the working and nonworking `recvfrom`'s, so I figured it was just an artifact of some kind ... Thanks, I'll try perror

Comment: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html According to this it doesn't work for WINSock calls

Comment: "*... a very huge number ...*" this number would be **very** interesting. Would you mind showing it to us?

Comment: 4200684.  This seems to be fairly repeatable across program reruns, not that I'm sure it'd be the same tommorow.

Comment: Without seeing more code, it might be impossible to help you. Try to set up a short example reproducing the issue.

Comment: I've more or less put the whole thing up for grabs...

Comment: `int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr);` should be `int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);`.

Comment: I clearly need to review my structure definitions/parameter details.. but alas, the only thing I've been able to effect at all so far is that bizarre error code.

Comment: It's not that I probably couldn't find some internet stuff to plagiarize, I want to find out what is wrong with this code on principle, if nothing else!

Comment: 1/ You have multiple threads accessing the same socket concurrently: UB. 2/ You have a global variable calling "socket()" which is UB, because it happens before WSAStartup has been called. 3/ You call WSAStartup > 1 time when it only needs to be called once at application startup, before you make any networking calls (such as 'socket()').

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use global `Socket`? And why are you declaring another `Socket` in main? You should better use the socket passed in `pthread_create` (just cast `args` in listenloop to `SOCKET *`). Global variables in multithreaded are a really bad idea (you need synchronization mechanism). And initialize your `struct sockaddr_in from` with zeros (for e.g. with `memset`, or just do as alk said : `struct sockaddr_in from = {0}`).

And also you are reading from one socket in two different threads without any kind of synchronization. This is bound to cause many errors.

And also I see a problem with `WSACleanup` and `recvfrom` in other thread. You don't know in what order will these two run (so you can also get `WSACleanup` before you can `recvfrom` in other thread).You can use `pthread_join` to wait for other thread to finish and then do `WSACleanup`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The code as posted would not work at all, due to declaring:

```
struct sockaddr_in* from;
```

and then using `from` like this:

```
r=recvfrom(Socket,message,_max_message_,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&SenderAddrSize);
```

You are paasing the address of the address of `struct sockaddr_in` instead of only its address.

Is shall be:

```
r=recvfrom(Socket,message,_max_message_,0,(struct sockaddr *)from,&SenderAddrSize);
```

However if doing so you are missing to allocate memory to `from`.

So propably

```
struct sockaddr_in* from;
```

is a typo and should have read:

```
struct sockaddr_in from = {0};
```

?

Comment: Sir... I implemented your changes as I understand them.  They did not effect the behavior of the code.